# Pandas conditionally creating a new dataframe using another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a list;

```
orig= [2, 3, 4, -5, -6, -7]
```

I want to create another where entries corresponding to positive values above are sum of positives, and those corresponding to negative values above are sum negatives. So the desired output is:

```
final = [9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 18]
```

I am doing this:

```
raw = pd.DataFrame(orig, columns =['raw'])
raw
   raw
0    2
1    3
2    4
3   -5
4   -6
5   -7

sum_pos = raw[raw> 0].sum()
sum_neg = -1*raw[raw < 0].sum()

final = pd.DataFrame(index = raw.index, columns = ['final'])

final
  final
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN

final.loc[raw >0, 'final'] = sum_pos
KeyError: "[('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w')\n ('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w')] not in index"
```

So basically i was trying to create an empty dataframe like raw, and then conditionally fill it. However, the above method is failing.

Even when i try to create a new column instead of a new df, it fails:

```
raw.loc[raw>0, 'final']= sum_pos
KeyError: "[('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w')\n ('r', 'a', 'w') ('r', 'a', 'w')] not in index"
```

The best solution I've found so far is this:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(raw>0, sum_pos, sum_neg), index= raw.index, columns=['final'])
   final
0    9.0
1    9.0
2    9.0
3   18.0
4   18.0
5   18.0
```

However, I dont understand what is wrong with the other approaches. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try grouping on `np.sign`, then `sum` and `abs`:

```
s = pd.Series(orig)
s.groupby(np.sign(s)).transform('sum').abs().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 18]
```

You're not aligning indexes.  'sum_pos' is a series with a single element that has an index of 'raw'.  And, you are trying to assign that series to a part of dataframe that doesn't have 'raw' as an index.

Pandas does almost everything using index alignment.  To properly do this you need to extract the values from the sum_pos series:

```
final.loc[raw['raw'] > 0, 'final'] = sum_pos.values

print(final)
```

Output:

```
   final
0    9.0
1    9.0
2    9.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott. This is helpful. I also posted a solution above. I am specifically trying to understand what is wrong with my first 2 approaches.